# How can an LC filter be designed for an inverter when the inductor (L) and capacitor (C) are connected in series?

Tags: passive-networks

I'm asking about the way to design an LC filter for the inverter with L and C linked in series to each other.

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: It would be good if you could add an image for each type of circuit that you mention in the question. LC filters may contain sections where L and C are in series. So, example circuit diagrams are required to make the question clear.

Comment: The ratio of reactive impedance to series damping resistance determines BW of resonance -3dB/f also defined by Q or gain at resonant f.

Comment: You should learn how to search. ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=LC+filter

Comment: thanks, and  we are  here  to learn  too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear.
The shape of the output signal depends on the input signal. If the input signal is a sine wave the output signal will also be a sine wave, with the same frequency but (in most cases) a different amplitude.
The reason for that is the fact that LCR combinations are linear circuits and linear circuits can not produce components with frequencies different from the frequency of the input sine wave.
For other (periodic) input signals the signal shape will generally be modified by a LCR network. A periodic signal which is not a pure sine wave consists of sum of sine waves with different frequencies. Each of these sine wave components will generally be damped differently by the filter which leads to a change of the signal shape. That's the reason why we build filters.

Comment: I used  the  LC after  full-bridge  converter so the signal will be  square wave.

Comment: Why do you think that the output of a full-bridge converter with a following LC-network is a square wave?

Comment: I meant the output of full-bridge will follow the LC  filter?  so here how to design the  LC filter  inverter  to get sinewave?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not choose my words correctly to ask a clear question.